# Xorg and Virtualbox break after installing Xen

Tags: xen

I installed XEN using these instructions

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen

Now when I rebooted virtualbox doesnt work, X doesnt work, lightdm doesnt work

How can I set it back to how it was before? I presume I want to revert the following actions:

Modify GRUB to default to booting Xen:

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_DEFAULT=.*\+/GRUB_DEFAULT="Xen 4.1-amd64"/' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

Can someone tell me how?

Comment: Please pastebin /etc/default/grub and ls -l /boot -- thanks

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1120182/
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1120183/

Answer (score 0):

To roll-back, set `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` in **/etc/default/grub**
then `update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to run X on domU, you can do it by following the instructions [here](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-VNC.html). i don't understand from your question what virtualbox has to do with it?